# Clearing up FRA (Flash Recovery Area) Space

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c, oracle18c

I am facing issues with the RMAN script that is primarily being used to clear up the FRA.

```
run {
delete force noprompt obsolete;
allocate channel for maintenance device type disk;
delete obsolete device type disk;
delete archivelog all backed up 2 times to disk;
crosscheck archivelog all;
delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
delete noprompt expired backup;
delete noprompt expired copy;
report obsolete orphan;
report obsolete;
crosscheck copy;
crosscheck backup of controlfile;
crosscheck backup;
delete noprompt expired backup of controlfile;
delete force noprompt expired copy;
delete force noprompt obsolete orphan;
delete noprompt expired archivelog all;
report obsolete recovery window of 7 days;
delete noprompt obsolete recovery window of 7 days;
backup as compressed backupset archivelog all;
delete noprompt archivelog until time 'sysdate-1' backed up 1 times to device type disk;
crosscheck archivelog all;
}
```

I was using this in the past which seemed to work out well. Lately, The script seemed bugged out. One of the many errors I get is below. The "Do you really" want to is applicable for every line of my RMAN prompt. I didn't paste the whole output here.

```
Do you really want to delete the above objects (enter YES or NO)? "delete archivelog all backed up 2 times to disk;" is an invalid response - please re-enter.

Do you really want to delete the above objects (enter YES or NO)? "crosscheck archivelog all;" is an invalid response - please re-enter.


RMAN-06207: WARNING: 3 objects could not be deleted for DISK channel(s) due
RMAN-06208:          to mismatched status.  Use CROSSCHECK command to fix status
RMAN-06210: List of Mismatched objects
RMAN-06211: ==========================
RMAN-06212:   Object Type   Filename/Handle
RMAN-06213: --------------- ---------------------------------------------------
RMAN-06214: Backup Piece    /OCI_Backup/testdev_backup/testdev_test3abc_1_1
```

Where did i go wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Purpose is to effectively free-up the FRA.

Comment: This question is better suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/